# Validacion campo int para que no me bote el sistema (data annotations)

Tags: c#, validación

Tengo un campo que almacena un `int` (solo deja almacenar hasta 10 dígitos) pero el problema es que por ejemplo si un usuario ingresa un numero de 15 dígitos me bota el sistema.

¿Existe alguna validación para evitar esto?

Código:

> [Range(0, 2500, ErrorMessage = "No se permiten números mayores a
>   2500")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta que te ha dado [Martin Desarrollador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/11270/martin-desarrollador) es correcta, pero te la pongo con ejemplos de código para que te hagas una idea:

```
    // En el caso de que tu variable sea un 'int'
    if (myVariable > 9999999999)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("El número sólo puede tener hasta 10 dígitos");
    }

    // En el caso de que tu variable sea un 'string'
    if (myVariable.Length > 10)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("El número sólo puede tener hasta 10 dígitos");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

2 formas, si mantener la variable como entera, entonces que el valor sea menor o igual a 99999999999999
En cambio, si es un string, y verificas el largo en un if.

Esa podría ser una validación sencilla.